# Сравнение двух списков и фильтрация их элементов в Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Пытаюсь создать ExpansionList во Flutter: у меня созданы две модели `CoffeeShop` и `CoffeeShopMenu`, но загвоздка в том, что я хочу не просто списком выводить значения из модели CoffeeShopMenu, а чтобы каждому **shopTitle** было присвоено свое значение **shopMenuTitle**. Например: названию "Strarbucks" принадлежит 'Latte and americano', для 'Dunkin doghnuts' -  'Matcha' и т.д

Я эту задачу понимаю так: сначала нужно отфильтровать при помощи метода `where` каждый список, а затем уже отфильтрованное пропустить через метод `forEach` внутри виджета, где forEach идёт через каждый элемент модели CoffeeShop и ищет своей элемент в модели CoffeeShopMenu. Грубо говоря, я хочу отфильтровать оба списка со строковыми значениями по их тайтлам.

Но никак не могу понять, как это правильно реализовать и на данный момент код представляет из себя вот такое:

```
class ExpList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop = <CoffeeShop>[
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Strarbucks'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Subway'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'MCCafe'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Coffee Shop'),
  ].where((element) => element.shopTitle == element.shopTitle).toList();

  List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu = <CoffeeShopMenu>[
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'Latte and americano'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'pie'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'sandwich'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'croissant'),
  ].where((element) => element.shopMenuTitle == element.shopMenuTitle).toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: coffeeShop.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            coffeeShop.forEach((element) {
              coffeeMenu.forEach((element) {
                return coffeeMenu;
              });
              return coffeeShop;
            });
            return ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(coffeeShop[index].shopTitle),
              subtitle: Text(coffeeShop[index].shopTitle),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: coffeeMenu.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Text(coffeeMenu[index].shopMenuTitle)
                      );})],
            );
          }),
```

Также при попытке раскрыть список выходит ошибка:

```
Assertion failed:
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#6b2e7 NEEDS-PAINT"
```

Я так понимаю, это связано с тем, что я пытаюсь прогнать через второй ListView.builder список с меню?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простой пример как это можно сделать:

```
void main() {
  final List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop = <CoffeeShop>[
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Strarbucks'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Subway'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'MCCafe'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Coffee Shop'),
  ];

  final List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu = <CoffeeShopMenu>[
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'Latte and americano'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'pie'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'sandwich'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'croissant'),
  ];
  
  final List<Coffee> coffee = uniteCoffee(coffeeShop, coffeeMenu);
  
  print(coffee);
  print(coffee[1].menu.shopMenuTitle);
  print(coffee[1].shop.shopTitle);
}

List<Coffee> uniteCoffee(List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop, List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu){
  if(coffeeShop.length != coffeeShop.length) return [];
  
  List<Coffee> temp = <Coffee>[];
  
  for(int i = 0; i<coffeeShop.length; i++) {
    temp.add(Coffee(coffeeShop[i], coffeeMenu[i]));
  }
  
  return temp;
}

class Coffee {
    Coffee(this.shop, this.menu);
  
  final CoffeeShop shop;
  final CoffeeShopMenu menu;
  
  @override
  String toString() => "Coffee(shop: $shop, menu: $menu)";
}

class CoffeeShop {
  CoffeeShop({this.shopTitle});
  
  final String shopTitle;
  
  @override
  String toString() => "CoffeeShop(shopTitle: $shopTitle)";
}

class CoffeeShopMenu {
  CoffeeShopMenu({this.shopMenuTitle});
  
  final String shopMenuTitle;
  
  @override
  String toString() => "CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: $shopMenuTitle)";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, @MiT а как быть, если используешь провайдер? Я делаю все, что вы написали, да, наконец-то заработал раскрывающийся список, но так как я пытаюсь использовать FutureProvider для чтения JSON-а, то используя ваш ответ - все равно "смотрит" на вот эту строчку:  `List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu = Provider.of<List<CoffeeShopMenu>>(context); //вот эту строчку он видит первой` Фильтровать через where уже пробовал

Comment: Все также, вы в build получаете coffeeShop и coffeeMenu, сочленяете модели через uniteCoffee в одну переменную и используете ее. Тут важно чтобы получения этих данных из JSON-а в Provider срабатывал раньше чем вы его начнете использовать в build.

Comment: Но если вдруг не получается обрабатывать раньше, то можно использовать StatefulWidget и переопределить в нем didChangeDependencies(): https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-provider-and-didchangedependencies-15678f502262